# Query a many to many field of referenced table using ORM

Tags: django, django-orm

My models are as follows:

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    states = models.ManyToManyField(State)

class ABC(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    app_user = models.ForeignKey(AppUser, null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to query my database for list of objects present in ABC model and I want to filter it according to the list of States.

I am trying something like this:

```
ABC.objects.filter(app_user__states__in = state_list).values('id','name')
```

But this is not working. Can I even access a many to many field like this or do I need to create a custom through table.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

For queryset:

```
ABC.objects.filter(app_user__states__in = [1,2]).values('id', 'name')
```

you'll get sql like this:

```
>>> print(ABC.objects.filter(app_user__states__in = [1,2]).values('id', 'name').query)

SELECT "test_abc"."id", "test_abc"."name" 
FROM "test_abc" 
INNER JOIN "test_appuser" ON ("test_abc"."app_user_id" = "test_appuser"."id") 
INNER JOIN "test_appuser_states" ON ("test_appuser"."id" = "test_appuser_states"."appuser_id") 
WHERE "test_appuser_states"."state_id" IN (1, 2);
```

Looks fine. Maybe it doesn't work as you expected?